# I am using Google map api V2 Play services lib also include.But app crash on both emulater and device. Here is my code

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

It give error that unfortunately map testing has stopped  I have add all permissions and
put correct value of key......
This is main activity Java file.

```
package com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
private GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maptesting)).getMap();
Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG).title("Hamburg"));
Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(KIEL).title("Kiel")
.snippet("Kiel is cool").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
```

Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.

```
 map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));
```

Zoom in, animating the camera.

```
 map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
 }
```

onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
 return true;
 }

}
```

This is XML file..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
android:id="@+id/maptesting"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is manifest..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

package="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps"


android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk


android:minSdkVersion="16"
android:targetSdkVersion="18" />



<permission


android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-feature


android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true" />


<uses-permission    
android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.permission. MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission  android:name="com.google. android.providers. gsf.permission.   
READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"


android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>

<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="Key Value" />
<application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: check logcat for errors. it helped me to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Add this tag to your Manifest.xml file:

```
  <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```